# Find $\operatorname r(\bf A)$ such that $\mathbf A^5=\mathbf0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

> $10\times10$ matrix $\mathbf A$ satisfies $\mathbf A^5=\mathbf0$. Find all posibilities of $\operatorname r(\mathbf A)$.

By Sylvester inequality, $\operatorname r(\mathbf A^2)\ge2\operatorname r(\mathbf A)-10$, then $\operatorname r(\mathbf A^3)\ge3\operatorname r(\mathbf A)-20$ and so on. We then have
$$0=\operatorname r(\mathbf A^5)\ge5\operatorname r(\mathbf A)-40\implies\operatorname r(\mathbf A)\le8.$$
However I only have the construction for $\operatorname r(\mathbf A)\le5$: $\operatorname{diag}\{0\dots,0,\underbrace{1\dots,1}_{\le5}\}$.

What about $6$, $7$, $8$?

Comment: I think we need to prove that $\operatorname r(\mathbf A)\ge6$ impossible...

Comment: It is impossible. You can consider the minimal polynomial of $A$ and its Jordan normal form.

Comment: How does that diagonal matrix satisfy $\mathbf{A}^5 = 0$? Isn't $\mathbf{A}^5 = \mathbf{A}$?

Comment: @youthdoo $r(A) \geq 6$ is only impossible if we're given that $A^4 \neq 0$. Otherwise, $A = 0$ is an example with $r(A) \leq 5$.

Comment: One important property of nilpotent matrix is about its [flag of subspaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_matrix#Flag_of_subspaces). Given that $1\le q\le n$ and given any finite sequence of nonnegative integers $(r_0,r_1,\ldots,r_q)$ with $r_0=n$ and $r_q=0$, there exists an $n\times n$ nilpotent matrix $A$ such that $A^q=0\ne A^{q-1}$ and $\operatorname{rank}(A^k)=r_k$ for $0\le k\le q$ if and only if the polygonal curve joining the nodes $(k,r_k)$ for $k=0,1,\ldots,q$ is strictly decreasing and convex.

Comment: @ronno It does produce $\bf0$. I checked and double-checked that by Mathematica.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that $r(A)$ denotes the rank of $A$ and that we are given that $A^4 \neq 0$.

Your proof that $r(A) \leq 8$ is correct. Here's an outline for a proof that we must have $r(A) \geq 4$:

- Show that for any matrix $A$ and $k \geq 1$, if $r(A^k) = r(A^{k+1})$, then $r(A^k) = r(A^j)$ for all $j \geq k$.
- Use the above to conclude that in our case, we must have
  $$
  r(A) > r(A^2) > r(A^3) > r(A^4) > r(A^5) = 0.
  $$
- Use this to conclude that $r(A) \geq 4$.

Here are examples where the rank attains all possible values $4,5,6,7,8$. Denote
$$
A_k = \pmatrix{M & 0\\0&M^k},
$$
where
$$
M = \pmatrix{0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0&0}.
$$
Verify that for $k = 1,\dots,5$, we have $A_k^4 \neq 0$, $A_k^5 = 0$, and $r(A_k) = 9 - k$.

Comment: And without the condition $A^4 \ne 0$ you can achieve $0, \dots, 3$ with $A = \mathrm{diag}(0, M^k)$ for $k = 5, \dots, 2$ resp.

Comment: Can you briefly explain the motivation of your construction?